# Поменять template.php после Ajax запроса (Битрикс)

Tags: php, ajax, битрикс

Есть компонент, который отрисовывает содержимое в несколько столбцов, количество столбцов хранится в $arResult["COLS"], моя задача состоит в том, чтобы при размере окна <= 768px принудительно задать $arResult["COLS"] = 1.

Я решил пойти через Ajax(Может это и не правильный путь): Отправляю Ajax запрос, в компоненте его обрабатываю:

```
if ($_POST["123"]) { 
$APPLICATION->RestartBuffer();
$arResult["COLS"] = 1;
exit();
}
```

Запрос отправляется и обрабатывается, но переменная остается прежней, как обновить эту переменную чтобы шаблон отрисовался в один столбец?

Comment: Не совсем понял, зачем вам ajax. Если вы хотите изменить количество столбцов до отдачи страницы -- вам не нужен ajax, а если после -- ваш шаблон на сервере уже роли играть не будет и делать это придется средствами js.

Comment: @rusgeli Пересобирать DOM дерево после подгрузки?

Comment: Зачем тут использовать сторону сервера? Тут банально нужно использовать JS и не парится.